# Mach port messages in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ipc, message

I am trying to use Mach port messages in Objective-C but I cannot find any documentation or working example.

Would you have any pointers to documentation or examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [NSMachPort](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMachPort_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation and http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/Concepts/ports.html

Answer (score 2):

This reference did help a friend, who was looking for the same.

http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/mach_msg_header.html

http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/mach_msg_descriptor.html

(Apple is now more closed source than before, again: All important API-documentations from Apple seem to be removed or redirected to the wrong pages. Unusable, IMHO.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ended up to use AppleEvents